# Почему не работает скрипт в ie?

Tags: jquery, javascript, internet-explorer

Почему не работает скрипт jquery в ie? Вот сайт http://x-raysystem.kz/

Comment: @harley, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что jQuery у Вас 2.x, а IE, видимо, не выше 8 (детали [на сайте jQuery](http://jquery.com/browser-support/)).

Если коротко, то используйте ветку 1.х или забудьте о IE версий до 8 включительно.